# Using the Spring RabbitMQ logback appender, how can I source config values to logback-spring.xml

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, logback

Using class `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender` according to the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#:%7E:text=Since%20logging%20is%20initialized%20before,entirely%20is%20via%20System%20properties.). What is best practice for sourcing connection information based on env.

I've tried passing the args in via command line ie [-DCONFIG_VALUE=foo] which worked fine, however is there a way to configure using terraform and logic inside the code base